# Altering htaccess for optional parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a htaccess rewrite rule that allows for 3 parameters to be passed with forward slashes. The 3rd parameter is optional. I'm now trying to change this to get a 4th, optional, parameter.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4 [NC,QSA,L] ^^
```

This code doesn't recognise the 4th parameter.

So I tried the following

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4 [NC,QSA,L] ^^
```

But this adds a required 4th parameter and it doesn't work if this 4th parameter is left off.

Any ideas how I can alter this to only require 2 parameters, with the 3rd and 4th being optional but recognised?

Any help would be appreciated, as would a little explanation if possible!

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of making one complicated rule, it is often advisable to make several rules and order those by descending specificity.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm not sure how time consuming that is for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?)?/?$ index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4 [QSA,L]
```